# ASP.NET MVC pop-up message blinker

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can anyone help me to explain how should we blink session time out pop up when user is on separate window?

I have built my app in asp.net mvc 3 and showing it with JS but finds most of the time user's are on separate window/tab and thus reported not to come across with the pop up and logged out.

Thanks.

Comment: How about using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to notify all open windows?

Comment: Browsers are just not built to do that. You can open an alert, but if the user isn't watching that window, they won't see it.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome appear to support [web notifications](http://caniuse.com/notifications).  You might look into that.